# How to convert large float values to int?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a variable containing a large floating point number, say `a = 999999999999999.99`

When I type `int(a)` in the interpreter, it returns `1000000000000000`.
How do I get the output as `999999999999999` for long numbers like these?

Comment: `999999999999999.99 is 1000000000000000.0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`999999999999999.99` is a number that can't be precisely represented in the floating-point format, so Python compromises and picks the closest value that can be represented. In this case, that happens to be 1000000000000000. That's why converting that to an integer gives you 1000000000000000.

If you need more precision than floats can provide, consider using [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal).

```
>>> import decimal
>>> a = decimal.Decimal("999999999999999.99")
>>> a
Decimal('999999999999999.99')
>>> int(a)
999999999999999
```

Comment: The variable ```a``` is already defined with the value mentioned in the question. The code already contains a line ```a = 999999999999999.99```.   In your code, you are declaring the value of ```a``` inside the ```decimal.Decimal()```. So basically, I need to get the value from ```a``` and then print it.

Comment: The value I'm passing to `decimal.Decimal` is not the same as the value assigned to `a` in the question. My value is a string literal. This is necessary to preserve the precision. If you do `a = decimal.Decimal(999999999999999.99)`, then `a` will be `Decimal('1000000000000000')` instead.

Comment: How do I convert it into a string an then use ```decimal.Decimal(string)```? ```a``` is already declared as float type.

Comment: If `a` is already a float, then you have permanently lost the precision and there's no way to get it back.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not `int`, the problem is the floating point value itself. Your value would need 17 digits of precision to be represented correctly, while double precision floating point values have between 15 and 16 digits of precision. So, when you input it, it is rounded to the nearest representable float value, which is `1000000000000000.0`. When `int` is called it cannot do a thing - the precision is already lost.

If you need to represent this kind of values exactly you can use the `decimal` data type, keeping in mind that performance does suffer compared to regular floats.