# Why doesn't conversion to int work on large float numbers in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion, integer

When I pass large `float` numbers into `int` or `math.ceil` or `math.float` the conversion in inaccurate.

```
>>> int(1000000000000000000000000.11)
999999999999999983222784
>>> ceil(10000000000000000000000000000.11)
9999999999999999583119736832
```

When I pass a large int to it, it works fine. This might be because it checks the type of number and finds it to be `int`.

```
>>> int(9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235122/how-to-convert-large-float-values-to-int) answer and found a workaround but I don't know **why** it behaves like this.

Comment: Floats have limited precision.

Comment: The conversion from float to int is fine. It's the conversion from *decimal literal in the source code* to float that's imprecise.